# void android.widget.ImageView.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android

I am using a simple java library file for Undo and Redo text as shown in the tutorial and sample android app but for me when I run the app it shows me the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
    at com.apps.primalnotes.Fragments.EditorFragment.textAction(EditorFragment.java:1023)
    at com.apps.primalnotes.Fragments.EditorFragment.onCreateView(EditorFragment.java:84)
```

Following is the library and method I am following on GitHub [enter link description here](https://github.com/Arowa-Z/TextUndoRedo)

And exactly i am doing the following

```
 EditorFragment extends Pantalla  implements TextUndoRedo.TextChangeInfo, View.OnClickListener{
    private TextUndoRedo TUR;
    private ImageView undo, redo;

 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editor, container, false);

        getActivity().setTitle("Editor");

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        imm =(InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        base = new DataBase(context, null);


    text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.texto);
    undo = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.undo);
    redo = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.redo);
    TUR = new TextUndoRedo(text, this);

            textAction(); "Showing error here"

            undo.setOnClickListener(this);
            redo.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
        public void textAction() {
            undo.setEnabled(TUR.canUndo());  "Showing error here"
            redo.setEnabled(TUR.canRedo());
        }

    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.undo:
                    TUR.exeUndo();
                    break;
                case R.id.redo:
                    TUR.exeRedo();
                    break;
```

Comment: have you initialized them ?

Comment: No. In the given example on GitHub, it is also not initialized.

Comment: where is your ImageView code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: your code are not  complete

Comment: If you check the link given in my question, i am doing exactly the same

Comment: Do not call interface method. It is called by libray's internal implementation. Check library source

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't have a "setContentView(R.layout.{file name of layout})".

Could you check it? It should be performed before using findViewById method.

Comment: I have that but just for simplicity, I edit my code here. If you can look at the tutorial link its simple there and I am doing the same. but getting this error in my case

Comment: By the stack trace, the 'undo' variable is null. So I recommend check the layout file has ImageView with "@+id/undo" or not.

Comment: It has nothing to do with ids. ids are fine

Answer (score 0):

Here the code from the Github source

```
btn_undo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_undo);
btn_undo.setOnClickListener(this);
btn_redo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_redo);
btn_redo.setOnClickListener(this);
```

And here the code from your code :

```
text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.texto);
undo = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.undo);
redo = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.redo);
TUR = new TextUndoRedo(text, this);
```

The sample using `Button` for the undo/redo and you using `ImageView`. Check what is your ImageView ID in xml. Same with other here, your undo/redo `ImageView` is Null.

Comment: It has nothing to do with ImageView or Button. I tried button widget also but giving me the same error.

Comment: The other possibility, are you sure that you are inflate the right xml layout. Null from widget cause the widget is not assign or its not on your right xml.

Comment: XML layout and ids are all fine. Error is just coming with the textAction(); call and the  undo.setEnabled(TUR.canUndo());  "Showing error here"
            redo.setEnabled(TUR.canRedo());

Comment: Yes I know, but logically you can set `something` to A if the A is not in there. If you say you have right assign for the `ImageView` my last advice is handle it with `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 0):

Check your XML. Your ImageView for undo & redo should have an id that looks like this,

```
android:id="@+id/undo
```

or

```
android:id="@+id/redo"
```